# how to print the serial number of jqgrid in reverse order

Tags: indexing, jqgrid

In a jqgrid we will have the index values(sl numbers) on the very first row these values are assigned internally by jqgrid. How to print in reverse order?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: i have posted the code below... i want the index values which are displayed in the very first row of jqgrid in the descending order.

Answer (score 0):

$("#predefinedProcessGrid").jqGrid({

```
        data: processTasks,
        datatype: "local",


        colNames: ["Assigned By", "Assigned To","Step Name","Created On","Expected Start Date", "Actual Start Date", "Actual End Date","Status","Priority","  IP Address","Past Due (ms)"],
        colModel: [{
                name: "assignedByUserName",
                index: "assignedByUserName",
                editable: false,
                align: "left",
                width: 130,
                sorttype:'int',

            }, {
                name: "assignedToUserOrOrgText",
                index: "assignedToUserOrOrgText",
                editable: false,
                align: "left",
                width: 130,

            },{
                name: "processStepName",
                index: "processStepName",
                editable: false,
                align: "left",
                width: 220,

            },{

                name: "formattedCreatedDateTime",
                index: "formattedCreatedDateTime",
                editable: false,
                align: "left",
                width: 150,

            } ,{

                name: "formattedExpectedStartDate",
                index: "formattedExpectedStartDate",
                editable: false,
                align: "left",
                width: 150,

            }, {
                name: "formattedActualStartDate",
                index: "formattedActualStartDate",
                editable: false,
                align: "left",
                width: 150,
                sorttype:'int',

            }, {
                name: "formattedActualEndDate",
                index: "formattedActualEndDate",
                editable: false,
                align: "left",
                width: 150,

            },
            {
                name: "formattedUserTaskStatus",
                index: "formattedUserTaskStatus",
                editable: false,
                align: "left",
                width: 130,
                sorttype:'int',

            }, {
                name: "formattedTaskPriority",
                index: "formattedTaskPriority",
                editable: false,
                align: "left",
                width: 100,
                sorttype:'int',

            }, {
                name: "userTaskFromIPAddress",
                index: "userTaskFromIPAddress",
                editable: false,
                align: "center",
                width: 120,
                sorttype:'int'
            }, {
                name: "millisPastDue",
                index: "millisPastDue",
                editable: false,
                align: "center",
                width: 100,
                sorttype:'int',

            }
        ],
```

//            cmTemplate:{resizable:true},
            rowNum: 1e5,
            pager: "#predefinedProcessPager",
            ignoreCase:true,
            gridview: true,
            rownumbers: true,
             sortable:true,
                  "resizable": true,
            viewrecords: true,
            reverse:true,
         // sortname: 'Expected Start Date',
//           sortorder: "desc",

```
        editurl: "clientArray",
                 sortorder: "desc",
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        height: 470,
        keys: true,
        hidegrid: false,
        loadComplete: function () {
            var e = this;

            setTimeout(function () {
                updatePagerIcons(e);
                enableTooltips(e)
            }, 0)
        },


    }
```